# Hadoop - How does reducer gets it data?

Tags: hadoop

I understand that the mapper produces 1 partition per reducer. How does the reducer know which partition to copy? Lets say there are 2 nodes running mapper for word count program and there are 2 reducers configured. If each map node produces 2 partitions, with the possibility of partitions in both the nodes containing same word as key, how will the reducer work correctly?

For ex:

If node 1 produces partition 1 and partition 2, and partition 1 contains a key named "WHO".

If node 2 produces partition 3 and partition 4, and partition 3 contains a key named "WHO".

If Partition 1 and Partition 4 went to reducer 1 (and remaining to reducer 2), how does the reducer 1 compute the correct word count?

If this is not a possibility, and partition 1 and 3 would be made to go to reducer 1, how Hadoop does this? Does it make sure a given key-value pair from different nodes always go to a same reducer? If so, how it does this?

Thanks,
Suresh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, since partition 1 and partition 3 both with the key 'WHO', it is guaranteed  that the two partitions went to the same reducer.

#### Update

In hadoop, the max number of reduce tasks one a tasktracker at any one time is determined by the `mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum` property.
And the number of reducers for a MapReduce job is set via `-D mapred.reduce.tasks=n`

> When there are multiple reducers, the map tasks partition their output, each creating one partition for each reduce task. There can be many keys (and their associated values) in each partition, but the records for any given key are all in a single partition. The partitioning can be controlled by a user-defined partitioning function, but normally the default partitioner—which buckets keys using a hash function—works very well.(Hadoop: The definitive guide)

So, the value with a specified key would always go to the same reducer.

Comment: This is interesting. Lets say partition 1 and partition 2 are produced by TaskTracker 1 and partition 3 and partition 4 are produced by TaskTracker 2. How does the task trackers knew that they need to send partition 1 and 3 to the same reducer? Do they talk each other and decides a common reducer based on key? -- Suresh.

Comment: @Suresh Since both TaskTracker1 and TaskTracker2's tasks are assigned by the common JobTracker, the number of partitions each TaskTracker would produce and the destination of each partition is determined by the JobTracker and send to each TaskTracker, there is no need to talk to each other among the TaskTrackers. The TaskTracker would even not aware of each other's existence. So, they just partition output as the JobTracker says and send each partition to the address as the JobTracker gives it.

Comment: Henry,I wonder if JobTracker has any control on the number of partitions created per TaskTracker. The reason is it can be controlled by the programmer as well by writing a Partitioner class. Here is what I think would happen: TaskTracker1 would create partition 1 and 2 and indicate the JobTracker which keys are part of each partition. Similarly, TaskTracker 2 will also do. This gives the JobTracker an idea of which keys are in which partition of task trackers. It will then look for the availability of reducers and ask the reducers to take and process partitions based on keys.Just my thought.

Comment: @Suresh the partitioner class is just to specify how each key are mapped to each partition, the default HashPartitioner return the partition using `getPartition(K2 key, V2 value, int numPartitions) { return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numPartitions;}`. So, You may note the number of Partitions is not determined by the partitioner class.