# Map Reduce flow in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, pseudocode

I'm learning Hadoop using the book `Hadoop in Practice`, and while reading chapter 1 i came across this diagram:

[image]

From the Hadoop docs:(http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current2/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/Reducer.html)

#### 1.Shuffle

> Reducer is input the grouped output of a Mapper. In the phase the framework, for each Reducer, fetches the relevant partition of the output of all the Mappers, via HTTP.

#### 2.Sort

> The framework groups Reducer inputs by keys (since different Mappers may have output the same key) in this stage.
>   The shuffle and sort phases occur simultaneously i.e. while outputs are being fetched they are merged.

While i understand that `shuffle` and `sorting` happens at the same time, it's not clear to me how the framework decides which `reducer` receives which `mapper` output. From the docs, it seems that each `reducer` has a way to know which `map`output to collect, but i can't understand how.

So my question is, given the mappers output above, the final result is always the same for each reducer? If so, what are the steps to achieve this result?

Thanks for any clarifications!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hadoop - How does reducer gets it data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10527271/hadoop-how-does-reducer-gets-it-data) - see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20757318/what-two-different-keys-go-to-the-same-reducer-by-the-default-hash-partitioner-i and http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the [Partitioner](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Partitioner.html) that decides how to distribute the output of mappers to different reducers.

> Partitioner controls the partitioning of the keys of the intermediate map-outputs. The key (or a subset of the key) is used to derive the partition, typically by a hash function. The total number of partitions is the same as the number of reduce tasks for the job. Hence this controls which of the m reduce tasks the intermediate key (and hence the record) is sent for reduction.

Comment: Thanks, this made it a little bit clearer, i'll need to meditate to understand this!

Comment: You can also tell your mapreduce program to set the no of reducers using the job property...`job.setNumReduceTasks(No_of_reducers_you_want)` .Do note that the argument is a int element, So you can explicitly define the no of reducers based on how many partitions you want